# function run on the immediate window but not on cell sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me to understand where is the problem,
I want simply the value from each carrier from end of any month.
The loop method is not a problem,
this is my function:

```
 Function Tmese (c As String, m As Integer) As Integer 'C as Carrier, as m month
        Dim y As Date, x As Variant
         y = CDate (1 & "/" & m + 1 & "/" & 2016) - 1 'to have the end of the month add one month to c and I subtract one day
         With Worksheets (c)
             Set x = .Columns (1) .Find (y,,, xlWhole)
             If X Is Nothing Then
                 Tmese = .Cells (x.Row, 5) 'found max dates into a month to retreive corrispondence fair
             else
                 Exit Function 'not found
             end If
         end With
 end Function
```

if I play my function on the immediate windows the result is immediate but, if I put the function in the cell like = Tmese ("GLS"; 2) nothing happens
Why?! ??!

Comment: You shouldn't get anything in the immediate window either - that code doesn't even compile.

Comment: in the immediate windows (to test the function) I put:  debug.Print Tmese("GLS",2) and I retreive 1308, correct!

Comment: You are missing a `If` before `X Is Nothing...`

Comment: @GôTô error on write this tread, the code on my wb is correct and not run.

Comment: Actually I think you mean `If Not x Is Nothing Then` instead of `If X Is Nothing Then If Not`

Comment: You are complicating things are, use the `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth` function instead of your `y = CDate (1 & "/" & m + 1 & "/" & 2016) - 1` .

Comment: @ShaiRado rigth, I've updated my code with yours tips, but anyway on immediate windows run, but  into excel sheet not!

Comment: @Fabrizio  update your post with ur updated code, run it in debug mode and see on what line you are getting a runtime error

Comment: Try ?Tmese ("GLS", 2) in the immediate window.

Comment: `error on write this tread, the code on my wb is correct and not run.` - so the code is correct in your workbook, but not this thread?  For me your code fails on `Tmese = .Cells....`  Your code is saying `If x Is Nothing then set Tmese to equal column 5 on the row that x is found on` But x is not found, so it's nothing and you get an `object variable not set` error.  It should be, as @GôTô said: `If Not x Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @SJR some I wrote, if I put ?Tmese ("GLS", 2) in the immediate window (or debug.print  Tmese ("GLS", 2) in the immediate window in my example) the result is 1309, in my cell is 0

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Hi, GôTô show me some transcription error on my code, have been corrretti, sorry.
Now the core in this tread is the some on my wb, then on the immediate windows it run but into excel sheet not

Comment: did you try putting a break point within the function ? You will come to know which statement is failing and the reason.

Comment: @MukulVarshney, I haven't error, I told that on immediate windows the code run then the code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on most of the comments above:

1. You need to make sure `Find` is successful by using `If Not x Is Nothing Then`.
2. You can use the `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth` to find the end of the month of `m`.

**Function *Tmese* Code**

```
Function Tmese(c As String, m As Integer) As Integer  ' C as Carrier, as m month

    Dim y As Date, x As Variant

    y = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(CDate("1/" & m & "/2016"), 0) ' find add of the month of m
    With Worksheets(c)
        Set x = .Columns(1).Find(What:=CStr(y))
        If Not x Is Nothing Then
            Tmese = .Cells(x.Row, 5)  ' found max dates into a month to retreive corrispondence fair
        Else
            Exit Function 'not found
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

***GLS worksheet Data***

[image]

How to apply in another worksheet

[image]

Comment: that right, CStr(expression) was resolutive, I tried to test string format (manually from cells to cells) now you've lighting my way. thank